# too many template parameters in template template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to implement some template template code as the following, it work well on GCC 7, but failed to compile on Clang 6. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>

template <template <typename, typename> class Op>
class Function
{
};

template <typename A, typename B, bool is_f = std::is_floating_point<A>::value || std::is_floating_point<B>::value > struct Operator;

template <typename A, typename B>
struct Operator<A, B, false>
{};


template <typename A, typename B>
struct Operator<A, B, true>
{};

using FunctionOperator = Function<Operator>;


int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    std::cout << "hi!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Compile errors:

```
tmp.cpp:19:35: error: template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter
using FunctionOperator = Function<Operator>;
                                  ^
tmp.cpp:8:1: note: too many template parameters in template template argument
template <typename A, typename B, bool is_f = std::is_floating_point<A>::value || std::is_floating_point<B>::value > struct Operator;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tmp.cpp:3:11: note: previous template template parameter is here
template <template <typename, typename> class Op>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clang clearly has problem with fact that the basic `Operator` struct template has 3 not 2 arguments and thus refuses to accept it inside `Function` template. 
According to answer to this question [Template template argument causes compiler error under Clang but not GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51284346/template-template-argument-causes-compiler-error-under-clang-but-not-gcc/51284523#51284523) Clang is wrong and GCC is standard compliant in this issue. Anyway here's a quick workaround for this issue:

```
template <template <typename, typename> class Op>
class Function
{
};

template <typename A, typename B, bool is_f = std::is_floating_point<A>::value || std::is_floating_point<B>::value > struct Operator;

template <typename A, typename B>
struct Operator<A, B, false>
{};


template <typename A, typename B>
struct Operator<A, B, true>
{};

template<class A, class B>
using Op = Operator<A, B>;

using FunctionOperator = Function<Op>;


int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    FunctionOperator o;
    std::cout << "hi!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

It works both with gcc and clang.