# Template template argument causes compiler error under Clang but not GCC

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

While helping with problem noted in [too many template parameters in template template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282912/too-many-template-parameters-in-template-template-argument/51283457#51283457) a question arose in my head: which compiler is right about the compilation in this case:

```
template <template <typename, typename> class Op>
class Function
{
};

template <typename A, typename B, bool is_f = std::is_floating_point<A>::value || std::is_floating_point<B>::value > struct Operator;

template <typename A, typename B>
struct Operator<A, B, false>
{};


template <typename A, typename B>
struct Operator<A, B, true>
{};

using FunctionOperator = Function<Operator>;


int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    std::cout << "hi!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

GCC 7+ compiles it with no errors. Clang 6 and later gives errors showing that there is a problem with `Operator` template passed as template argument:

```
tmp.cpp:19:35: error: template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template parameter
using FunctionOperator = Function<Operator>;
                                  ^
tmp.cpp:8:1: note: too many template parameters in template template argument
template <typename A, typename B, bool is_f = std::is_floating_point<A>::value || std::is_floating_point<B>::value > struct Operator;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tmp.cpp:3:11: note: previous template template parameter is here
template <template <typename, typename> class Op>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Obviously, it treats it as 3-arguments template even though the default third argument is supplied. So here is the question, which of the compilers is right? Does standard say anything about such situations?

PS I do not need a workaround for these kinds of problems as it is pretty simple.  I just want to know "who is right"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gcc is correct. Clang seems not in accordance with C++17.

Since C++17 ([CWG 150](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#150)), the default template arguments are allowed for a [template template argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_arguments) to match a template template parameter with fewer template parameters.

> ```
> template<class T> class A { /* ... */ };
> template<class T, class U = T> class B { /* ... */ };
> template <class ...Types> class C { /* ... */ };
>
> template<template<class> class P> class X { /* ... */ };
> X<A> xa; // OK
> X<B> xb; // OK in C++17 after CWG 150
>          // Error earlier: not an exact match
> X<C> xc; // OK in C++17 after CWG 150
>          // Error earlier: not an exact match
> ```

`Operator` has 3 template parameters, the 3rd one has default value, then it could be used as the argument for template template parameter `Op`, even it only expects two template parameters.

Comment: I don't see why some people (like Google's Android folks) force a severely flawed, apparently useless C++ implementation like Clang despite mankind has a working one...